# Inflector methods not working in my rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inflector

I found a method [humanize](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-humanize) that I want to use in my rails project.

app/views/audits/_show.html.erb

```
<%= humanize('inappropriate_writing') %>
```

but I get this error:

```
undefined method `humanize' for #<#<Class:0x00007fb4f1f98208>:0x00007fb4f39107a8>
```

Do some rails methods not work out of the box? Am I supposed to "include ActiveSupport::Inflector" somewhere? If so I can't work out where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `humanize` method like this `"inappropriate_writing".humanize` which will give output like `Inappropriate writing`.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  is it not weird tho that here: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-humanize it give the example like this: " humanize('employee_salary')  "  ...?